# Status Code: 0 Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: tooManyRetries Message: More than 3 retries encountered while sending the request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api

When we are trying to fetch meetings from Calendar using Graph API we are getting exception

Code for fetching calendar events:

```
GraphServiceClient service = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (request) =>
                    {
                        request.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                        await Task.FromResult<string>(null);
                    }));


eventResult = await service.Users[connectedAccountEmailID].Calendars[calendarId].CalendarView.Request(options)
                        .Select("id,subject,organizer,start,end,attendees,showas,isallday,seriesmasterid")
                        .Header("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"")
                        .GetAsync();
```

Exception We are getting is

```
exeptionType : System.AggregateException

Status Code: 0
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: tooManyRetries
Message: More than 3 retries encountered while sending the request.

   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.CalendarCalendarViewCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Service.Office365CalendarProviderService.<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<<GetCalendarMeetings>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I have checked the code and verified that we are not making any parallel calls at the same time but still getting throttled limit type exceptions.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Don't have any inside knowledge of Azure, but I noticed that the status code is 0. Even if the graph API server didn't send HTTP code 429 to designate too many requests, it would (probably) still send something other than 0. So unless the library you're using is parsing responses incorrectly, then either A.) your request is never reaching the server or B.) the server is instantly closing the connection. If you have the ability to do so, you can try either running a wireshark during the request, or step through a debugger to see at what stage the library stops.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the .NET SDK's built-in retry handler has re-tried a failing request the maximum number of times (See https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/2466fdca28d807b727497db7dc8c7767d513f62f/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/Middleware/RetryHandler.cs#L132-L137). Three times is the default max retry value.

Retries only happen with specific HTTP status codes (429, 503, or 504) so for some reason you're hitting that in your app. One thing you might try is to attempt this same API call using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer) with the same user. It may also be helpful to look at the rest of the fields on that AggregateException to see what the "real" exceptions were. A network capture may also expose more debug information.

If all of that doesn't provide an answer, you'll likely need to contact [support](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/support).

Comment: I checked with the same user through Graph Explorer but not getting any such exception. So I posted the same for further support as suggested- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/381873/getting-exception-while-fetching-busy-time-from-ca.html

Please look into it